# Leitura de arquivo txt em C e interpretação dos dados

Tags: c, arquivo, struct, gerenciamento-de-memória

Preciso realizar a leitura de arquivos txt em C e interpretar os dados de dentro dos arquivos. 
Os arquivos contem partes em TEXTO e outras em números DECIMAIS/INTEIROS. O que preciso é ler todo o arquivo e passar os números para uma estrutura de coordenadas cartesianas. Por exemplo, o conteúdo do arquivo é:

```
NAME : eil8
COMMENT : 8-city problem (Christofides/Eilon)
TYPE : TSP
DIMENSION : 8
EDGE_WEIGHT_TYPE : EUC_2D
NODE_COORD_SECTION
1 37 52
2 49 49
3 52 64
4 20 26
5 40 30
6 21 47
7 17 63
8 31 62
EOF
```

Preciso fazer a leitura e alocar os dados a partir de

```
1 37 52
2 49 49
3 52 64
4 20 26
5 40 30
6 21 47
7 17 63
8 31 62
EOF
```

em uma estrutura de maneira que fique mais ou menos assim:

```
coordenada.x[1] = 37;
coordenada.y[1] = 52;

coordenada.x[2] = 49;
coordenada.y[2] = 49;

...
```

Porém não tenho conhecimento suficiente sobre alocação dinâmica.
O que pensei:

```
1- abrir o arquivo
2- ler o arquivo linha por linha até encontrar "NODE_COORD_SECTION"
3- ler o arquivo linha por linha 
4- alocar dinamicamente os dados em uma estrutura tipo matriz x * y
5- parar em EOF
```

Tenho conhecimento do código até a parte da leitura do arquivo, mas como cada arquivo terá um número diferente de linhas, como fazer essa leitura sem um tamanho pré definido?

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o principal problema aqui seja a alocação dinâmica. Obviamente a única forma de saber o quanto de espaço é necessário é percorrendo o arquivo até o fim. Como é feio e contraproducente percorrer o arquivo todo e depois percorrê-lo mais uma vez, o que você tem que fazer é alocar a memória à medida em que ela é requerida.

Pensando em pseudocódigo, seria algo assim:

1. Inicia alocando 100 itens;
2. Se pedir mais, aloca mais 100;
3. E assim por diante...
4. Liberar o restante não usado ao final, se for o caso

A função perfeita para esse trabalho é `realloc` [void* realloc (void* ptr, size_t size);](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/). Ela é usada para aumentar ou diminuir o total de memória alocada, para mais ou para menos.

Precisa ter uma série de cuidados ao usá-la:

1. Seus parâmetros são o ponteiro que se quer realocar, e o tamanho total que se quer realocar;
2. Ela retorna ou `NULL`, caso em que não foi possível alocar a memória desejada, ou retorna um ponteiro para a nova área alocada (que não é necessariamente idêntica à original);
3. Os valores dantes escritos no vetor alocado são mantidos como eram, ainda que a posição absoluta na memória mude.

Por ora estas são as ideias. Se for o caso, eu tento um código de verdade.